# Does MongoDB's filemd5 have ability to set readPreference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, database-replication, gridfs

I have a file storage service built in Node/Meteor, which utilizes GridFS, and it is replicated across several containers. What I'm currently trying to find, is if this piece of code is actually aware of the read/write consistency

```
db.command({
  filemd5: someFileId,
  root: 'fs'
}, function callback(err, results) {
  ...
})
```

I'm uploading file in chunks, and after merging all chunks into a single file that command is executed. And I have a feeling that it's using secondary members (i got a couple md5 values which are of empty file - `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`). Is there any documentation or additional settings for it?

Those 2 params are the only options described in docs.. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/filemd5/

UPDATE
The exact code for merging the chunks is here in a 3rd party package:

```
         cursor = files.find(
            {
               'metadata._Resumable.resumableIdentifier': file.metadata._Resumable.resumableIdentifier
               length:
                  $ne: 0
            },
            {
               fields:
                  length: 1
                  metadata: 1
               sort:
                  'metadata._Resumable.resumableChunkNumber': 1
            }
         )
```

https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection/blob/master/src/resumable_server.coffee#L26

And then there are line 111-119 which execute filemd5 first, and the run an update on the file

```
                @db.command md5Command, (err, results) ->
                   if err
                      lock.releaseLock()
                      return callback err
                   # Update the size and md5 to the file data
                   files.update { _id: fileId }, { $set: { length: file.metadata._Resumable.resumableTotalSize, md5: results.md5 }},
                      (err, res) =>
                         lock.releaseLock()
                         callback err
```

https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection/blob/master/src/resumable_server.coffee#L111-L119

After writing the last chunk, the `cursor = files.find()` is launched with all the merging stuff, hence if read preference is `secondaryPreferred` then they might not still be there? Should that code be refactored to use primary only?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you upload and merge the chunks? You can take a look at the mongo logs or the `files` and `chunks` collections for the full document details. For now, I will place the docs and stuff in an answer.

Comment: @MasterAM i've included the original source code (it is coffeescript, but should give a glance about the actual queries ran there)

Comment: After looking a bit into it, it seems not to behave the way I anticipated. I cannot afford the time to dig any deeper, so I don't think that I can help you beyond the references in my answer. It appears that the md5 supplied by the admin command is not taken from the `files` document, but probably stored elsewhere when the file is saved.

Comment: @MasterAM thanks! I will be studying the results to see if the problem persists

Answer (score 2):

GridFS creates 2 collections: `files` and `chunks`.

A typical `files` entry looks like the following:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58cfbc8b6900bb31c7b1b8d9"),
    "length" : 4,
    "chunkSize" : 261120,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-03-20T11:27:07.812Z"),
    "md5" : "d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00",
    "filename" : "foo.txt"
}
```

The `filemd5` administrative command should simply return the `md5` field of the relevant file document (and the number of chunks).

> **files.md5**
>   An MD5 hash of the complete file returned by the filemd5 command. This value has the String type.
>
> source: [GridFS docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#the-files-collection)

It should represent the full file's hash, or at least of the one originally saved.

> **What is the ‘md5’ field of a files collection document and how is it used?**
>   ‘md5’ holds an MD5 checksum that is computed from the original contents of a user file. Historically, GridFS did not use acknowledged writes, so this checksum was necessary to ensure that writes went through properly. With acknowledged writes, the MD5 checksum is still useful to ensure that files in GridFS have not been corrupted. A third party directly accessing the 'files' and ‘chunks’ collections under GridFS could, inadvertently or maliciously, make changes to documents that would make them unusable by GridFS. Comparing the MD5 in the files collection document to a re-computed MD5 allows detecting such errors and corruption. However, drivers now assume that the stored file is not corrupted, and applications that want to use the MD5 value to check for corruption must do so themselves.
>
> source: [GridFS spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst)

If it is updated in such a way such that the driver's `mongoc_gridfs_file_save` is not used (for example, streaming), the `md5` field will not be updated.

> Actually, further reading the spec:
>
> > Why store the MD5 checksum instead of creating the hash as-needed?
> >     The MD5 checksum must be computed when a file is initially uploaded to GridFS, as this is the only time we are guaranteed to have the entire uncorrupted file. Computing it on-the-fly as a file is read from GridFS would ensure that our reads were successful, but guarantees nothing about the state of the file in the system. A successful check against the stored MD5 checksum guarantees that the stored file matches the original and no corruption has occurred.
>
> And that is what we are doing. Only the mongoc_gridfs_file_save will calculate a md5 sum for the file and store it. Any other entry points, such as streaming, expect the user having created all the supporting mongoc_gridfs_file_opt_t and properly calculating the md5
>
> source: [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-965)